# Android - trying to create buttons by region in a round interface

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

This is the UI for my project and I'm trying to have those levels mapped as buttons, is there a simple way to do so?

I'm sorry if this is already answered here, I tried my best to find another questions like this.

Thanks.

[image: UI]

Comment: Check this library. https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/ImageLayout You can define buttons for each one of your areas and you can define exactly the absolute positions of each button.

Comment: Thank you, I will read this and try to use it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to use a `Button` Widget. Each of the target (press-able) could be defined as a type of `View` (`RelativeLayout`,`LinearLayout`, etc.) and then in the layout XML for that fragment/activity hosting this view, you can set the clickable attribute to 'true'. You can then set an event listener on that view. That will give you more flexibility than using `Button`.

Comment: Could you help me with that? I'm trying to figure out how I can use that to help.